# Matlab interpolation for a figure

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I want to plot some points based on an image of a hand. Then, I should use lagrange interpolation method to plot all the points together so that the shape of a hand would appear. I faced a difficulty in making the interpolation as function is only valid for one to one or many to one. However, the shape of a hand would need 2 points that might have the same x-coordinate but different y-coordinate. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16400330/1714410) useful.

Answer (score 2):

You have a sequence of n points (x,y) which describes the shape of the hand. In matlab you could represent this by 2 vectors.

```
X=[x1;x2;..;xn]
Y=[y1;y2;..;yn]
```

Now you can describe the shape of the hand by a [parametric equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation).

```
x = f(t);
y = g(t);
```

To use lagrangian interpolation you have to choose a vector t of length n

```
t=[t1;t2;t3;...;tn] #(with t increasing)
```

For each element ti in t the following statement should be true.

```
xi = f(ti)
yi= g(ti)
```

This means that the curve described by f(t) and g(t) goes through all points you provided. You could find an equation for f(t) by using lagrangian interpolation on the vector x and g(t) by doing the same with y.

Now you just have to evaluate [f(t),g(t)] in a lot of values for t.

## conclusion

To state the solution shortly. Represent the shape of the hand in parametric form. By doing this you could just do lagrangian interpolation seperately on the vector of x-coördinates and y-coördinates. (Make sure you use the same parameter and that that parameter is equal in any given point.)

Comment: How to write the the parametric interpolation?